# Bot doesn't delete the second attachment it sends but it does delete the first attachment

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
const { MessageAttacment} = require('discord.js');
const Discord= require('discord.js');
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE4MDAzNDEwNzg5ODI4MTEw/barack-obama-12782369-1-402.jpg');
const attachment2 = new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://s.france24.com/media/display/3230a2b4-97f9-11ea-96e4-005056bf18d4/w:1280/p:16x9/063_1225292516.webp')

module.exports = {
    name: 'who is joe',
    description: "shsh be quiet",
    activates: 'who is joe',

    callback: (message, arguments, text) => {message.channel.send
        ('Here take a peek',attachment)
        .then(m => { m.delete({timeout:3000})})
        setTimeout(t => { message.channel.send(attachment2)}, 5000)
        .then(m2 => { m2.delete({timeout:3000})})


}}
```

Error:

```
.then(m2 => { m2.delete({timeout:3000})})
        ^

TypeError: setTimeout(...).then is not a function
    at callback (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\discord bot\responses\joe.js:15:10)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\discord bot\responses\responseBase.js:37:9)
    at Client.emit (ev
```

Comment: Your `.then()` callback should be inside the `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
const { MessageAttacment} = require('discord.js');
const Discord= require('discord.js');
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE4MDAzNDEwNzg5ODI4MTEw/barack-obama-12782369-1-402.jpg');
const attachment2 = new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://s.france24.com/media/display/3230a2b4-97f9-11ea-96e4-005056bf18d4/w:1280/p:16x9/063_1225292516.webp')

module.exports = {
    name: 'who is joe',
    description: "shsh be quiet",
    activates: 'who is joe',

    callback: (message, arguments, text) => {message.channel.send
        ('Here take a peek',attachment)
        .then(m => { m.delete({timeout:3000})})
        setTimeout(t => { message.channel.send(attachment2) 
          .then(m2 => { m2.delete({timeout:3000})})}, 5000)

}}
```